# Lubuntu 20.04: what do the files in /sys/power/suspend_states do?

Tags: lubuntu, filesystem

the `/sys/power/suspend_states/` directory has the following files:

```
ls -lhFArtS
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 success
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 last_failed_step
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 last_failed_errno
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 last_failed_dev
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_suspend_noirq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_suspend_late
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_suspend
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_resume_noirq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_resume_early
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_resume
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_prepare
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 failed_freeze
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Jun 12 17:51 fail
```

Most are `ASCII text` files, all of which have just one 0 in them. A few are of the `very short file` format, all of which are empty. What are these files needed for? Found nothing relevant on the [Filesystem Heirarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf), or online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/sys` folder is controlled by the Linux kernel.

You have to read some kernel [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/pm/devices.html) about it and find exact section then.